# How to send an ID through AJAX to a PHP file and display the result in a Bootstrap Modal

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a table where the rows are displayed dynamically based on the database records.

What I am trying to do is that when I click on one of the rows that it loads the Bootstrap modal with all of the information from the database for that specific record.

This is the code for each row that gets displayed and when I click it it displays the modal but the modal is empty without any data.

**Initial file**

`<tr class="issuesTable push" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" <?php echo "id='" . $row['Issue_ID'] . "'"; ?> >`

So I am trying to take this dynamic ID value and pass it to a file named **issueDisplayModal.php** to make the query and then display the details on the modal. Here is the query in the other file.

**code that should receive the ID**

```
$issueID = $_POST['record_id']
issueQue ="SELECT * FROM Issues WHERE Issue_ID = $issueID";
$result = $my_dbhandle->query($issueQue);
$numResults = $result->num_rows;
```

After this I do a series of echoes to print out the information on the modal which I got working (thankfully!).

This is the JQuery code that I'm trying to get to work to send the HTTP request to display the issueDisplayModal.php code on the modal based on the ID that I send it.

**AJAX that should call the file and send the ID variable**

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
   var $invoker = $(e.relatedTarget);
   var issue_id = $invoker.attr('id');

   $.ajax({
      type : 'post',
       url : 'issueDisplayModal.php', // in here you should put your query 
      data : 'post_id='+ issue_id, // here you pass your id via ajax .
                 // in php you should use $_POST['post_id'] to get this value 
   success : function(r)
       {
          // now you can show output in your modal 
         $('#mymodal').show();  // put your modal id 
         $('.something').show().html(r);
       }
   });

})
```

This is the modal that should display the result from **issueDisplayModal.php**

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Issue Details:</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">

        <div class="something">

         **results should be displayed here**

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Create Task</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Close</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: so what happens when you click that button? can you clarify the bits that are not working for you, what is missing? any error messages? it would also help if you would post more details about where the javascript is hooked up, e.g. a complete HTML test page would be good...

Comment: The modal shows up but it's empty. I don't know if the php file is not being called or if it's not passing the ID correctly. Let me post a bigger piece of code. I just didn't want to overwhelm with all the code.

Comment: Is anything in r when you write it to the console? Right before you call .show(), do a console.log(r) to see if anything is in the response

Comment: I don't think there is anything in r.

Comment: @AbrahamA.If you haven.t figure out yet, the problem is in `<tr>` and then `var $invoker = $(e.relatedTarget);`

Comment: @AbrahamA. and in success function, these are wrong `$('#mymodal').show();` and `$('.something').show().html(r);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of errors in your approach and unnecessary code

```
<tr class="issuesTable push" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" <?php echo "id='" . $row['Issue_ID'] . "'"; ?> >
```

Change `<?php echo "id='" . $row['Issue_ID'] . "'"; ?>`  to `data-id="<?php echo $row['Issue_ID'];?>"`

```
<tr class="issuesTable push" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-id="<?php echo $row['Issue_ID'];?>" >
```

Then in [bootstrap modal events](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events) you can fetch `id` in one variable, no need to define 2 variables

```
var $invoker = $(e.relatedTarget);
var issue_id = $invoker.attr('id');
```

you can get `id` like this;

```
var invoker = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
```

down the road, in Ajax method, `success: function` is all wrong, you don't need to show the modal again `$('#mymodal').show();` and again don't need to show the div `something` `$('.something').show().html(r);` so `success: function` should be

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'post',
   url: 'issueDisplayModal.php', // in here you should put your query 
   data: 'post_id=' + invoker, // change issue_id to invoker .
   // in php you should use $_POST['post_id'] to get this value 
   success: function (r) { //Change
       // now you can show output in your modal 
       //$('#mymodal').show(); // Don't need this
       $('.something').html(r); // Don't need .show() Here
   }
});
```

**PHP**

In Ajax, data is `post_id` but you are fetching `$_POST['record_id']`, it should be `$_POST['post_id'];`

```
$issueID = $_POST['post_id'];
issueQue ="SELECT * FROM Issues WHERE Issue_ID = '$issueID'";
$result = $my_dbhandle->query($issueQue);
$numResults = $result->num_rows;
```

To get the result in modal

```
echo $numResults;
```

SideNote: Make sure the script is DOM ready.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   //Put your script Here
});
```

That's all and it will work out of the box.

**Edit**

Final Script looks like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
        var invoker = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
        alert(invoker);
        $.ajax({
           type: 'post',
           url: 'issueDisplayModal.php',
           data: 'post_id=' + invoker,
           success: function (r) {
               $('.something').html(r);
           }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for the incredible help! This was my first attempt at AJAX and as you have shown, I was not doing it correctly. I will go ahead and implement your solution. Thank you very much once again!

Comment: I made the changes to the code but I think the problem now is that the Javascript is not firing when the modal opens. So basically this line of code is not firing as it should.

    $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e){}

Comment: set an `alert(invoker);` to see if id is passing to modal also can change `show.bs.modal` to `shown.bs.modal`

Comment: Nope, it isn't firing for some reason. I added these two alerts and neither shows up. alert(invoker); alert("modal script loaded"); I had changed the shown.bs.modal right before your comment. :(

Comment: and you made the suggested changes in modal call button `data-id="<?php echo $row['Issue_ID'];?>"`

Comment: Yep, I even checked the HTML after refreshing the page and that is displaying correctly to the website. It seems like for some reason the script is not firing when the modal opens. It's crazyness!

Comment: is your script DOM ready? also check browser console log, see if any error there

Comment: That I'm not sure. I put the code you gave me like this. $(document).ready(function(){
 $('.something').innerhtml(r); 
}

Don't know if that's right.

Comment: wait, let me straight the script in answer and you can try that

Comment: IT WORKED!!!! Thank you so much!!! WOW!!! You have no idea how big my smile is right now!

Comment: Happy coding as well!

Answer (score 0):

Because you have the data-toggle options selected, you are probably binding more than one click event on the tr element.

If you are not getting a success response, then the only reason the modal is popping is because of these attributes.

If you want to trigger the ajax call on the same click event use the build in modal events

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var $invoker = $(e.relatedTarget);
    var issue_id = $invoker.attr('id');
   // now do the $.ajax() call and test for a response
 })
```

Here's a working example of this kind of thing:
http://www.bootply.com/WTgjFfxWSl#

Comment: You're right about the binding of more than one click. I removed the data-toggle options and it stopped pulling the empty modal. I'll try your idea and see how that goes. Thank you!

Comment: You can use the data-toggle attribute, you just need to hook into the show.bs.modal event prior to calling ajax. I'll update the example some more to show you how you can get the value from the invoker

Comment: Ok. I tried your first code and sadly it didn't work :(

Comment: Updated the example. To clarify, you still need the data-toggle attributes to trigger the modal. You don't need the $('push').click though

Comment: I am most sad to say that it didn't work. I feel like I am so close to it working though. It's just some little thing.I updated my AJAX code in the description so you can see what I changed it to.

Comment: Ok, I'll take a look. Thank you so much for your help!